# Oracle 11g SQL assignment

Tags: oracle11g

I'm really battling with a question in my Textbook that I can't quite understand. The entire book (A guide to SQL 9th Edition) focuses on Oracle 11g via SQL commands in the SQL workshop of oracle AE.

However, the latest chapter (Chapter 8) talks about using PL/SQL in Procedures and the wording of the question is confusing to me, can someone help me understand what the answer is?

```
    22. When you run the following SQL command, the result is "no data found." 
    You know that one record should be retrieved. 
    Rewrite the SQL command using a function that will retrieve the record.

    SELECT ITEM_NUM, DESCRIPTION PRICE
    FROM ITEM
    WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'patience';
```

What is confusion to me is that the question appears to be in relation to a procedure and yet the wording and sample code makes me thing they are asking for a standard command. I also don't see how the error can be given if there is supposed to be a record matching the criteria.

Comment: They want you to add a built-in or standard function to the query.  I'll  you a hint that Oracle is case sensitive.

Comment: In other words they are wanting me to make use of a function to change case such as:


  SELECT ITEM_NUM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE
  FROM ITEM
  WHERE UPPER(DESCRIPTION) = ‘PATIENCE’;

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to use the upper or lower function to specify case as surmised by question poster.

```
SELECT ITEM_NUM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE 
FROM ITEM 
WHERE UPPER(DESCRIPTION) = ‘PATIENCE’;
```